# RegEx for capturing groups using dictionary key

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, regex-negation, regex-group

I'm having trouble displaying the right named capture in my dictionary function. My program reads a .txt file and then transforms the text in that file into a dictionary. I already have the right regex formula to capture them.

Here is my File.txt:

```
file Science/Chemistry/Quantum 444 1
file Marvel/CaptainAmerica 342 0
file DC/JusticeLeague/Superman 300 0
file Math 333 0
file Biology 224 1
```

Here is the [regex link](https://regex101.com/r/ozuj0S/1) that is able to capture the ones I want:

By looking at the link, the ones I want to display is highlighted in green and orange.

This part of my code works:

```
rx= re.compile(r'file (?P<path>.*?)( |\/.*?)? (?P<views>\d+).+')
i = sub_pattern.match(data) # 'data' is from the .txt file
x = (i.group(1), i.group(3))
print(x)
```

But since I'm making the .txt into a dictionary I couldn't figure out how to make .group(1) or .group(3) as keys to display specifically for my display function. I don't know how to make those groups display when I use `print("Title: %s | Number: %s" % (key[1], key[3]))` and it will display those contents. I hope someone can help me implement that in my dictionary function.

Here is my dictionary function:

```
def create_dict(data):
    dictionary = {}
    for line in data:
      line_pattern = re.findall(r'file (?P<path>.*?)( |\/.*?)? (?P<views>\d+).+', line)
      dictionary[line] = line_pattern
      content = dictionary[line]
      print(content)
    return dictionary
```

I'm trying to make my output look like this from my text file:

```
Science 444
Marvel 342
DC 300
Math 333
Biology 224
```

Comment: You could read the file line by line, use `m = re.search(r'file ([^/\s]*).*?(\d+)', line)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/CyGDSi/1)) to search for a match on a line and `if m:` you could append `"{} {}".format(m.group(1), m.group(2))` to the output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see how that is possible Thanks. How can I use that to my dictionary function because I have to make the text in the file to a dictionary and pull those groups to be displayed?

Comment: See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/TpDx1K). But you probably want [something like this](https://ideone.com/ESpdlm).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes! Something like this link helped. It just answered my question. Thank u

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55673523/3832970) below.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was waiting for you to post, so I can give you a check mark. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create and populate a dictionary with your file data using

```
def create_dict(data):
    dictionary = {}
    for line in data:
        m = re.search(r'file\s+([^/\s]*)\D*(\d+)', line)
        if m:
            dictionary[m.group(1)] = m.group(2)
    return dictionary
```

Basically, it does the following:

- Defines a `dictionary` dictionary
- Reads `data` line by line
- Searches for a `file\s+([^/\s]*)\D*(\d+)` match, and if there is a match, the two capturing group values are used to form a dictionary key-value pair.

The regex I suggest is

```
file\s+([^/\s]*)\D*(\d+)
```

See the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=file%5Cs%2B(%5B%5E%2F%5Cs%5D*)%5CD*(%5Cd%2B)) explaining it:

[image]

Then, you may use it like

```
res = {}
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    res = create_dict(f)
print(res)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ESpdlm).

Answer (score 1):

You already used named group in your 'line_pattern', simply put them to your dictionary. re.findall would not work here. Also the character escape '\' before '/' is redundant. Thus your dictionary function would be:

```
def create_dict(data):
    dictionary = {}
    for line in data:
        line_pattern = re.search(r'file (?P<path>.*?)( |/.*?)? (?P<views>\d+).+', line)
    dictionary[line_pattern.group('path')] = line_pattern.group('views')
    content = dictionary[line]
    print(content)
    return dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/KZS6G5/1) might help you to divide your inputs into four groups where group 2 and group 4 are your target groups that can be simply extracted and spaced with a <kbd>space</kbd>:

```
 (file\s)([A-Za-z]+(?=\/|\s))(.*)(\d{3})
```

[image]